# Giving 'NoneType' object attributes

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Is it possible to assign attributes to the `'Nonetype' object` to tell Python what to do if they are called?

Here is my problem:

I have a class that functions as a library to store instances of `myOtherObject`. Before adding an instance, it first checks if that key already exists and then appends the data to the instance assigned to that key rather than overwriting it.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.myLibrary = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if key not in self.myLibrary:
            self.myLibrary[key] = myOtherObject(name=item[0], attr1=[item[1]], attr2=[item[2]])
        else:
            self.myLibrary[key].attr1.append(item[1])
            self.myLibrary[key].attr2.append(item[2])

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.myLibrary:
            return self.myLibrary[key]
        else:
            return None #???
```

When retrieving data from the library it should check if the key exists too, and only return the assigned object if the key exists. This works fine or calling just the object, however not when calling the attributes of that object:

```
>>> o = MyClass()
>>> o['key1'] = ['name1','b','c']
>>> o['key1']
<__main__.myOtherObject instance at 0x05509B48>
>>> o['key1'].attr1
'b'
>>> o['key2']
>>> o['key2'].attr1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attr1'
```

Can I somehow tell Python not to do anything and just return `None` when attributes `attr1` and `attr2` are called from the `'NoneType' object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably the wrong question to ask. The proper (pythonic) thing to do there in the `__getitem__` method is to raise `KeyError` exception. Then you handle that exception in the caller, or higher up in an appropriate place that can deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to assign attributes to the 'Nonetype' object

No.

```
>>> o = None
>>> o.foo = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> setattr(o,'foo',1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> getattr(o,'foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

> Before adding an instance, it first checks if that key already exists and then appends the data to the instance assigned to that key rather than overwriting it.

This is a classic use case for a defaultdict:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
d['foo'].append(1)
print d #=> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'foo': [1]})
```

> When retrieving data from the library it should check if the key exists too, and only return the assigned object if the key exists. This works fine or calling just the object, however not when calling the attributes of that object:

OK. What do you want to happen when the key does not exist?

> Can I somehow tell Python not to do anything and just return None when attributes attr1 and attr2 are called from the 'NoneType' object?

What does this mean? If you attempt to access an attribute which does not exist, you get an exception, as above. The solution would be to handle the exception, and return `None`; but it would be *much* better to let the exception propagate, because `None` is not a valid input.

---

In summary, everything you want can be achieved with a defaultdict. Probably don't create your own class.

Comment: I tried defaultdict. Problem is that my myOtherObject has more than 10 attributes and several methods - here it is just simplified. So to make it work with deafultdict I would need at least three levels of lists for each key. And that is too confusing to work with, which is why I wanted objects where the attributes are named.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to retrieve and assign values to (and use methods) by the o['key'].attr - but only when o['key'] exists. Maybe I'll be forced to check if the key exists outside my main class before trying the use/assign it.

Comment: @totoro2 Absolutely none of this suggests that you need multiple levels of lists. Your question doesn't really disclose what problem you are trying to solve, but I am almost certain you are taking the wrong tack.

Comment: Sorry. To clarify: I have several levels of objects. Instances of myOtherObject is holding multiple other objects too - and I need to be able to access attributes and methods in the lowest class. E.g.  `o['key'].myThirdObject.myList.append('value')`. Class methods here makes it easier to assign values because they can check if the value already exists on each level and then append instead of overwriting.

Comment: @totoro2 So, do that then. I really don't see the problem here.

Comment: That's okay. Keith answered the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getattr`:

```
>>> o = None
>>> print getattr(o, "attr1", None)
None
```